# React CSS can't use image from public

Tags: reactjs

I create a project with `create-react-app project_name`, and then I tried to use a image from public folder as background with this code in css
`background-image: url('/images/ernestDrum.jpeg');`

and then I got this error
`./src/App.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/App.css) Error: Can't resolve '/images/ernestDrum.jpeg' in 'E:\project\ernest\src'`
in my previous project, I use the same code and it's works

Comment: you are probably calling the image from the wrong directory or the image is in the wrong directory itself. Could you share your file tree for us to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same error after updating react-scipts from 3.x.x to 4.x.x
and found this issue https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9870

Roll back to 3.x.x can solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

[CRA Docs - Using the Public Folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder):

> ...we normally encourage you to import assets in JavaScript files instead.

[CRA Docs - Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/):

> You can import a file right in a JavaScript module.

CRA does provide a way to use the public folder (1st link), but I would instead recommend placing images directly in `/src` (you could still use an `/images` folder). CRA's webpack set up will handle the rest. Note that you'll want to use a relative import:

```
background-image: url('./images/ernestDrum.jpeg');
```